# Last modification time of a Contact on Android

Tags: android, contacts

I need to get the last modification time of a Contact: 
I try to use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP, but in my emulator
it always returns 0. Any hint?

Comment: CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP relates to the last time the contact's Presence information was updated, not the last time the contact was updated.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So do you know how can I get the right last modification time of a Contact?